# Why my API is slow when invoked thru Threading in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

Can anyone help me to understand why the execution time is increasing when I go with Threading.

I am following the code from this [link](https://github.com/nikhilkumarsingh/async-http-requests-tut)

My Flask API code, say API1.py looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import torch

loaded_mdl = torch.load("/folder1/Tuned_Model_2.bin")

import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

import resource
soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (hard, hard))

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_ans',methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_ans():
    quest = request.json
    question = quest['question']
    context = quest['context']
    try:
        query = str(question)
        context  = str(context)
        to_predict = [{
        "context": context,
        "qas": [{
            "question":query,
            "id": random.rand(),
            
        }],
        }]
        try:
            start_predict_time = time.time()
            answers, _ = loaded_mdl.predict(to_predict)
            end_predict_time = time.time()- start_predict_time
        except Exception as e:
            #some logic
            
        
        doc = nlp(context)

        for sent in (doc.sents):
            #some logic with answers
            ans_text = processed_answer
            
        return str(end_predict_time)+"@#$"+ans_text
        
    except Exception as e:
        return "error"

if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    app.run(host='host1',port=port_1,threaded = True)
```

I have two more codes:  API2.py and API3.py  with same logic but the difference being the changes in port numbers , say port_2, port_3 and the location of bin files.

loaded_mdl = torch.load("/folder2/Tuned_Model_2.bin")
loaded_mdl = torch.load("/folder3/Tuned_Model_2.bin").

If I invoke the API code in sequential manner :

```
import requests
URL = 'http://host:port_1/get_ans'

def fetch(session, url):
    with session.post(url,json=json_) as response:
        print(response.text)

def main():
    with requests.Session() as session:
        for _ in range(3):
            fetch(session, URL)

start_time = time.time()
main()
print (f"Total time - {time.time() - start_time}")
```

My execution time :

```
0.8482604026794434@#$A.  ans1  
0.7749121189117432@#$A.  ans1
0.7759121189117432@#$A.  ans1
Total time - 4.10665225982666
```

So, I have invoked the API thrice sequentially and each had an average execution time of 0.84 secs and total execution time was 4.1 secs.

I tried with Threading and my code is :

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
import time

URL1 = 'http://host:port_1/get_ans'
URL2 = 'http://host:port_2/get_ans'
URL3 = 'http://host:port_3/get_ans'

json_ = {......}
def fetch(session, url):
    with session.post(url,json=json_) as response:
        print(response.text)

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            executor.map(fetch, [session] * 3, [URL1,URL2,URL3] )
            # executor.shutdown(wait=True)
            
start_time = time.time()
main()
print (f"Total time - {time.time() - start_time}")
```

The execution time :

```
3.9919259548187256@#$A. ans1
4.5576255321502686@#$A.  ans1
4.61368727684021@#$A.  ans1
Total time - 4.729625225067139
```

Why the execution time is increasing inspite of Threading? How can i bring down the execution time? Thanks.